# iOS build to target 4" screens only

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Is there a way to build a release for the App Store that only targets 4" screens (e.g. will only run on iPhone 5+, iPod Touch 5th Gen+)?

Comment: Keep in mind that an iPhone-only app run on an iPad will be run like it is on a 3.5" iPhone. So you must support 3.5" and 4" screens.

Comment: Embrace autolayout. Xcode 5 has nice previews with the assistant editor for how your views will look on 3.5" and 4" screens.

Comment: **Apple will reject your app for sure**

Comment: @FahimParkar Citation needed.

Comment: can you tell us what exactly you are trying to do? may be we will have solution for what you are trying to do... why you don't want app with iphone 4s screen? why only iphone 5 and above?

Comment: The app is to be paired with hardware which is only available for iPhone 5 and above. I suppose iPod Touch 5th Generation isn't needed if that's easier.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's impossible. You can select only minimum iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing iPod touch 5th gen, you can build only with armv7s so it only runs on iPhone 5+ (and you can try to add "armv7s" to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Info.plist key) 
But maybe Apple could reject that binary or the App Store App could be unable to filter that.

Comment: It's "losing", not "loosing". And this won't work really because it doesn't solve the problem running the iPhone-only app on the iPad.

Comment: I'm not saying its a perfect solution.. locking out 3.5" users might not be a good idea either..